# How to get accurate CPU usage for a process on a multi-processor / multi-core system

Tags: .net, multicore, performancecounter

Or maybe the question is more like "What am I doing blatantly wrong here?"

I have a test app which does nothing but watch its own cpu usage.  It looks a little something like this:

```
protected PerformanceTrace()
{
   Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
   this.cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", currentProcess.ProcessName);
   this.coreCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
}

private int coreCount;
private DateTime lastCpuRead = DateTime.MinValue;
private float _cpuUsage;
private float CpuUsage
{
   get
   {
      if ((DateTime.Now - this.lastCpuRead) > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
      {
         this._cpuUsage = this.cpuCounter.NextValue();
      }
      return this._cpuUsage / this.coreCount;
   }
}
```

The CpuUsage property is read very frequently.  Here's the thing:

On my machine, `Environment.ProcessorCount` produces a value of 2.  However, the value coming from the counter is often up to 800.  What I am assuming is it has something to do with multiple cores and hyperthreading.  What can I do to get the actual value that I'm looking for? (The total % processor time for this particular process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rigt - you have to divide the number from Performance Counters by the number of CPUs times the number of real threads per CPU - one per core, plus one per core if hyperthreading is a factor.

In C# I don't know how to determine this.  In native code you can use [GetLogicalProcessorInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [its associated structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686694%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to count the logical processors, including those that share a core.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Now how do I determine the number of threads per CPU?

Comment: Or the number of cores, rather.

Comment: Thanks!  Maybe I can figure out how to make that work for me.

Comment: Alternatively, you might be able to use Performance Counters to give you a count of logical processor instances implicitly.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Environment.ProcessorCount provides the number of logical processors, not physical processors; which is why I was surprised by the results I'm seeing.